# Jqgrid headers on two or more rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following problem:
I need to put on two or more rows header content of a Jqgrid.
I saw the example provided by Zac on [jqgrid double headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628451/jqgrid-double-headers) under alternatives, but by changing only the css I get no change on the grid.
Is it possible to have a more complete example in order to reproduce the behavior?
Thanks
Angelo

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want have multi-line column headers. You can do this with following additional CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    th.ui-th-column div{
        white-space:normal !important;
        height:auto !important;
        padding:2px;
    }
</style>
```

After that you will have columns like here
[image]

In the example the text 'Amount in EUR' was wrapped automatically and in the text from the first header the line break was made explicitly with 'Inv
No'.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641400/problem-with-wrapping-jqgrid-column-headers-on-ie/3641561#3641561) you will see the link to the demo.

**UPDATED**: In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246506/how-to-wrap-single-column-header-text-into-multiple-lines-in-jqgrid/7256972#7256972) you will find more recent code.

Comment: thanks a lot, oleg for your prompt reply. It works like a charm. Regards, angelinux

Comment: +1 Awesome I was just about to ask this exact question in the hopes that Oleg would answer it ... but he already has.

Comment: +50 bounty added and will be for Olegs answer. Just have to wait (1 days) before it can be awarded.

Comment: @Oleg: This "patch" is working very strange with column resizing. You can resize column if you drag only the top 20-30 px of the header cell.

Comment: @netme: Thanks. You can use `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {height:100% !important;}` additionally to fix the problem.

Comment: @Oleg: I added `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {height:100% !important;}` style but in column if resized to more rows, dragging in lower part of border still does not work

Comment: @Andrus: In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithWordWrappedColumns.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246506/how-to-wrap-single-column-header-text-into-multiple-lines-in-jqgrid/7256972#7256972) on your question I used the value *in px* with "!important". It works better as my old suggestion `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {height:100% !important;}`.