# jqgrid formatting a complex object

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a function on my server code that returns a list of `ElementRow` objects:

```
public class ElementRow {
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public YearData CurrentYear { get; set; }
    public YearData PreviousYear { get; set; }
}

public class YearData {
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

These classes generates a json like this one:

```
{"d":
    {
        "Total":2,
    "Page":1,
    "Records":30,
    "Rows":[
        {"AreaID":0,"CurrentYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":2},"PreviousYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":2}},
        {"AreaID":1,"CurrentYear":{"Value1":5,"Value2":4},"PreviousYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":2}},
        {"AreaID":2,"CurrentYear":{"Value1":2,"Value2":1},"PreviousYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":2}},
        {"AreaID":3,"CurrentYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":3},"PreviousYear":{"Value1":1,"Value2":2}}
    ],
    "UserData":null
    }
}
```

I have defined the colModel to support this data structure and would like to create a custom formatter function to format object of type `YearData` in one column. My colModel is as follow:

```
$("#dashboard").jqGrid({
    url: wsBaseUrl + 'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod',
    colNames: ['Area Name','Current Year', 'Previous Year'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'AreaName', index: 'AreaName', width: 120, template: colTextTemplate },
        { name: 'CurrentYear', index: 'CurrentYear', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: YearDataFormatter },
        { name: 'PreviousYear', index: 'PreviousYear', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: YearDataFormatter }
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: "AreaID"
    },
    pager: $('#dashboard_pager'),
    sortname: 'AreaName',
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: '250',
    rownumbers: false,
    gridview: false,
    subGrid: true,

    //subgrid definition omitted
});
```

and then defined the `YearDataFormatter` function as follow:

```
function YearDataFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var table = "<table><tr>";
    table += "<td>" + cellvalue.Value1 + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + cellvalue.Value2 + "</td>";
    table += "</tr></table>";
    return table;
};
```

Anyway when I try to execute this function the problem is that inside the `YearDataFormatter` function the value of `cellvalue` parameter is undefined while, looking at it with the debugger, there is a valid value inside the `rowObject` parameter.

How can I access correctly the value of that cell?

Also, is there any chance to modify the header for a particular column? I would like to create a two-line header but if I add markup inside the `colNames` option the header height does not change accordingly.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't posted the JSON or XML data which are used to fill the grid and the definition of jqGrid. The local data or in case of the usage of `loadone:true` the internal data will be saved and all works in another way. So the custom formatter should be used depend on the settings.

Because I have not enough information I try to guess. I suppose that you should use

```
function YearDataFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var table = "<table><tr>",
        cellData = rowObject.CurrentYear; // or like rowObject[2]
    table += "<td>" + cellData.Value1 + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + cellData.Value2 + "</td>";
    table += "</tr></table>";
    return table;
};
```

The best would be to change the format of data which the server use for the `date` and use ISO 8601 date format. If you use .NET you can use ["o" or "O" formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#42669a7d-9130-4650-8e7f-3cb8fe78e9f2) of the `DateTime`. In the case you can use `formatter:'date'` or `formatter:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat:'ISO8601Long'}`.

**UPDATED**: I am sure that you use much more default settings in the jqGrid definition. Without additional settings you can't read the JSON data. After small modification the demo read the data and I don't see any problem with the custom formatter which you use: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Lorenzo.htm):

[image]

You can compare the demo with youth to see the differences.

About your second question (multiline data in the grid header) I recommend you to look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896420/jqgrid-headers-on-two-or-more-rows/4898901#4898901):

Comment: Please note that I have edited my question to add the grid definition as well as the JSON returned from the server. Your suggestion works very well, unfortunately does not permit me to have a generic formatter to use in both columns as I would. Finally now that you can see the json data you will see that the data it's not of the type DateTime. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Yes there was a small typo in my code for the first question. For the second one: great!