# how to custom header jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

i want create jqGrid like this
[image]
I could divid body jqGrid i write this code

```
var data = [[1, 45, "E123", "1/1/11", "Done", 100], [2, 46, "E124", "1/12/11", "Done", 100]];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ["SNO", "OrderID", "Location", "Date", "Status", "Amount"],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'SNO',
        index: 'SNO',
        width: 60},
    {
        name: 'OrderID',
        index: 'OrderID',
        width: 90,
        formatter:orderFmatter},
    {
        name: 'Location',
        index: 'Location',
        hidden: true},
    {
        name: 'Date',
        index: 'Date',
        width: 80,
        formatter:dateStatusFmatter},
    {
        name: 'Status',
        index: 'Status',
        width: 80,
        hidden: true},
    {
        name: 'Amount',
        index: 'Amount',
        width: 80}
    ],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
});

var names = ["SNO", "OrderID", "Location", "Date", "Status", "Amount"];
var mydata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}

function orderFmatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
{
    return "<div>" + cellvalue + "</div><hr /><div>" + rowObject.Location + "</div>";
}

function dateStatusFmatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
{
    return "<div>" + cellvalue + "</div><hr /><div>" + rowObject.Status+ "</div>";
}
```

this code create this grid
[image]

in this grid i want divid header like body  grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jqGrid supports [header grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar). If you need just place multiline text in the column header you can implement this in more simple way.

The values in `colNames` can be HTML fragments. So you should place the code which you need in the corresponding item of `colNames` and add additional CSS which force to use `auto` height of the column headers instead of fixed height used by jqGrid per default.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultilineTextInColumnHeaders.htm) place in the column header of the last column the HTML fragment

```html
<div style="height: auto; padding: 4px 0;">
    <span>Shipped</span><hr /><span>via</span>
</div>
```

and uses additionally the CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-th-column>div {height: auto}
```

As the result one get the grid as on the picture below

[image]

Comment: thanks for help me, but i have one question, when use this solution i can not sorting with column Via, and sort just by Shipped. i want when user click with Via list sort by Via and when user click with shipped grid sorted with shipped. thanks.

Comment: @Pouya: The sorting icons will be placed in the same `<th>`. So you have to add more code to make all working. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4898901/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935).